# How to update param in update in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, updatemodel

When I receive a solicitation, I try to change my date to `nil`, but it's not working. It doesn't save in database.

```
def update
  @solicitacao = Solicitacao.find(params[:id])
  if @solicitacao.respondido == false
    @solicitacao.attributes = {:data_resposta => nil}
  end
  if @solicitacao.update_attributes(params[:solicitacao])
    redirect_to(@solicitacao, :notice => 'Solicitacao atualizada.')
  else
    render :action => "edit" 
  end
end
```

Comment: I talked to my friend, and him suggest to me make this verification in models... well i add in model a new validate like this: 
unless self.respondido
      self.data_resposta = nil;
    end

Answer (score 0):

If you change it, you need to save it!

```
@solicitacao.save
```

This will return a boolean, so you can handle an error if it occurs.

Comment: Actually, [`update_attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/update_attributes) not only updates the attributes but also "requests that the record be saved." Were you implying that the OP should use `save` instead of `update_attributes`?

Comment: like this? http://pastie.org/8189840 ... still not working, it doesn't save in database

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that `update_attributes` return false if it fails, I guess you can try something like this :

```
def update
 @solicitacao = Solicitacao.find(params[:id])
 if @solicitacao.respondido == false && @solicitacao.update_attributes( :data_resposta => nil )
  redirect_to(@solicitacao, :notice => 'Solicitacao atualizada.')
 else 
  render :action => "edit" 
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is checking the database's field when calling `if @solicitacao.respondido == false`, updating `@solicitacao` value, and then using `update_attributes` to save with  `params[:solicitacao]` parameter. Hence what you changed won't be saved, because the value isn't in `params[:solicitacao]`.

You have to change what you need in `params[:solicitacao]`, change the field `data_resposta` to `nil` and then it should work.

On the other hand, you can use `model.errors` to see where it went wrong. I don't think you'll get any error, because `update_attributes` actually works. It's just not what you wanted to save.

Comment: but it's changing and saving only atributte data_respota? or all form?

Comment: it should be all form, check what your params[:solicitacao] has

Comment: And I am at loss, why do you check what's already saved in database? Aren't you supposed to check `params[:solicitacao][:data_resposta]`?

Comment: well, i can try later...but now running on validate model, thanks